# Problems with hold in Matlab 2008a

Tags: matlab, figure

I'm trying to plot multiple graphs onto one figure inside a loop in Matlab, and `hold` doesn't seem to be working.  I can't post images, or I would show the output, but only the last graph from the loop and the graph outside the loop are being plotted.

I've tried putting `hold` both inside and outside the `for` loop without any difference.  Can somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong or offer a suggestions for a better way of doing this?  I'm using Matlab r2008a.

Thanks!

```
figure
colors = ['b','r','g','m'];
hold on
for det = 1:4
    plot(tvals,DOxy(:,det),colors(det));
end
plot(tvals,mOx,'k')
xlabel 'Time (s)'
ylabel '\Delta Oxy (\muM)'
legend('Probe 1','Probe 2', 'Probe 3','Probe 4')
hold off
```

Comment: Maybe `DOxy(:,1:3)` is `0` or `NaN` for some reason? Then it would *seem* like nothing is being plotted.

Comment: Like @Schorsch said, it think it should work.

Comment: the plotted points are going to be too small, did you consider that? maybe it can not be seen properly in the monitor and you should watch closer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using hold on correctly :

```
x = -pi:.1:pi;
figure
colors = ['b','r','g','m'];
hold on
for det = 1:4
    plot(x,det*sin(x),colors(det));
end
plot(x,cos(x));
```

Hence, there might be an error somewhere in your code.

Comment: Did you run this in R2008a?

Comment: R2007b and R2010a, so i suppose it should work in R2008a as well.

Comment: Yep - I had made a mistake earlier and was plotting the exact same graph four times.  `hold` was working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
figure;
colors = ['b','r','g','m'];
for det = 1:4
    plot(tvals,DOxy(:,det),colors(det));hold on;drawnow
end
plot(tvals,mOx,'k');
xlabel('Time (s)');ylabel('\Delta Oxy (\muM)');
legend('Probe 1','Probe 2', 'Probe 3','Probe 4');
```

you do not need hold off.
and the drawnow helps to update the plot in each loop, so you can see the changes little by little.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't help.  I'm still only seeing the last graph.  Thanks for the advice, though!